# Left outer join in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

**LINQ query**

```
from rc in context.RC
join r in context.R on rc.RId equals r.Id 
join c in context.C on rc.CId equals c.Id 
join f in context.F on rc.FId equals f.Id into fg
from f in fg.DefaultIfEmpty()
join e in context.E on rc.EId equals e.Id into eg
from e in eg.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

**Generated SQL is**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[RC] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[R] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[F] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[FId] = [Extent4].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[E] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[EId] = [Extent5].[Id]
```

**What I want to get is**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[RC] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[R] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[C] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[F] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[FId] = [Extent4].[Id]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[E] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[EId] = [Extent5].[Id]
```

Not sure what am I missing in my LINQ query

**Screen Shot of the code**

[image]

**Update**

Based upon comment by @GertArnold, `RC-F` (tables) and `RC-E` (tables) are in `N-1` association, where `RC` should hold a valid id key reference for `F`, but in `RC` table, some `F` **ids are zeros**, which is skipping data when I do `inner join`.

So now how can I force Entity-Framework/LINQ to generate `LEFT JOIN` syntax without modifying my DB schema

Comment: In lambda syntax, `Join` refers to `Inner Join` and `GroupJoin` is `Left Outer Join`

Comment: The LINQ query is fine and should generate `LEFT JOIN`. What ORM are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev Entity Framework 6

Comment: This definitely generates `LEFT JOIN`. Can you show the full query (or reproducible example)? Most likely you have `where` clause that turns `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER`

Comment: @IvanStoev I know it is Left join, as a matter-of-fact, I have been using it all these days. For this query something is not right.

Comment: All I'm saying that creating a model and running the provided LINQ query in my EF (latest 6.1.3 if that matters) test environment generates 2 inner + 2 left joins as expected.

Comment: I think that RC-F and RC-E are n-1 associations where the 1-side is required. EF knows the right member can't be null and doesn't generate an outer join.

Comment: @GertArnold As usual, straight to the point! I think you right, that should be the answer. If it's not an explicit `where`, it should be some other knowledge (obviously :)

Comment: @GertArnold if that is the case, how can I handle it?

Comment: If that's the case --only you can confirm that. But if it is, there's nothing to "handle" because you get correct data. But you may as well replace the outer joins by inner joins. Better: replace the joins by navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right, RC-F and RC-E are n-1 association, where RC should hold a valid id key for F, but in RC table, for reference of F id, we have zeros, which is skipping data when I do inner join. So now how can I force entity framework to generate Left join syntax with out modifying my DB schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon comment by @GertArnold, RC-F (tables) and RC-E (tables) are in N-1 association, where RC should hold a valid id key reference for F, but in RC table, some F ids are zeros, which is skipping data when I do inner join.

This is how I ended up querying the results.

```
            List<MyType> myResults;
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                var results = (from rc in context.RC
                    join r in context.R on rc.RId equals r.Id
                    join c in context.C on rc.CId equals c.Id
                    select rc).ToList();

                myResults = results.Select(rc => new MyType
                {
                    Id = rc.Id,
                    Rule = new IdName
                    {
                        Id = rc.R.Id,
                        Name = rc.R.Name
                    },
                    Conjuction = new IdName
                    {
                        Id = rc.C.Id,
                        Name = rc.C.Conjuncation
                    },
                    Field = new IdName
                    {
                        Id = rc.F!= null ? rc.F.Id : 0,
                        Name = rc.F!= null ? rc.F.Name : null
                    },
                    Expression = new IdName
                    {
                        Id = rc.E!= null ? rc.E.Id : 0,
                        Name = rc.E!= null ? rc.E.Expression : null
                    },
                    DisplayOrder = rc.Order,
                    Value1 = rc.Value,
                    Value2 = rc.Value2
                }).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: So you *have* navigation properties! Or did you add them? Anyway, you can remove the first `ToList`, so you continue building the expression in the second part. Then you can simply do `Id = rc.E.Id`, etc. because everything runs as SQL (which has no null reference exception).

Comment: I had navigation properties. will remove the .ToList(), but we cannot force EF LINQ to construct left outer join when there are navigation properties?